# Get a ImageView value

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new into the "Android World" and I've a problem getting a ImageView value, suppose I've a ImageView somewhere in my layout file and I want to retrieve is value, i.e. the value in the "android:src" tag. How I can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the resource file is compiled the ImageView simply refers to a resource integer in the R file. So the image "src" value will simply be a value once you've retrieved it, and not the string value you placed in your layout file.

Nonetheless, I think you can get that ID through your ImageView's getResources() method.

**EDIT**: I'm wrong, turns out you can get the string through [Resources.getString(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int%29)

**EDIT 2**: Looks like getResources might not contain the ID for you either, an Android engineer already answered a similar question: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/84d31b244163821d?pli=1

Comment: Upvoted: thanks for taking the time to update the answer, even after being accepted